# Getting GPO setting values

Tags: powershell, group-policy, gpo, windows-server-2019

I want to get settings for GPO policies in the Windows Server 2019 such as the"Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only".

The usual way would be to go to this path in the Local Group Policy Editor manually.

> Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only

However, is there a way to get the values via Powershell? I have tried using  `Get-GPOReport` and  `gpresult /R` but both results are not what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

So i wrote a functin for this a while ago

```
Function Parse-SecPol($CfgFile){ 
    secedit /export /cfg "$CfgFile" | out-null
    $obj = New-Object psobject
    $index = 0
    $contents = Get-Content $CfgFile -raw
    [regex]::Matches($contents,"(?<=\[)(.*)(?=\])") | %{
        $title = $_
        [regex]::Matches($contents,"(?<=\]).*?((?=\[)|(\Z))", [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Singleline)[$index] | %{
            $section = new-object psobject
            $_.value -split "\r\n" | ?{$_.length -gt 0} | %{
                $value = [regex]::Match($_,"(?<=\=).*").value
                $name = [regex]::Match($_,".*(?=\=)").value
                $section | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $name.tostring().trim() -Value $value.tostring().trim() -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | out-null
            }
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $title -Value $section
        }
        $index += 1
    }
    return $obj
}

Function Set-SecPol($Object, $CfgFile){
   $SecPool.psobject.Properties.GetEnumerator() | %{
        "[$($_.Name)]"
        $_.Value | %{
            $_.psobject.Properties.GetEnumerator() | %{
                "$($_.Name)=$($_.Value)"
            }
        }
    } | out-file $CfgFile -ErrorAction Stop
    secedit /configure /db c:\windows\security\local.sdb /cfg "$CfgFile" /areas SECURITYPOLICY
}
  
$SecPool = Parse-SecPol -CfgFile C:\test\Test.cgf
$SecPool.'System Access'.PasswordComplexity = 1
$SecPool.'System Access'.MinimumPasswordLength = 8
$SecPool.'System Access'.MaximumPasswordAge = 90

Set-SecPol -Object $SecPool -CfgFile C:\Test\Test.cfg
```

`Parse-SecPol` will create a File `-CfgFile {FileName}` and then creates a PSObject from the Config

`Set-SecPol` will turn the PSObject `-Object {Parse-SecPol Object}` back into Configfile `-CfgFile {FileName}` and update the GPO